# R, getting correlation between all variables in a dataset, pairwise

Tags: r, correlation

New to R,

i know i can get correlation between 2 variables with cor.test(x,y)

Now i have a dataframe of like 11 variables, is there a command or procedure to get all the correlations of pairwise variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the `mtcars` database in R.

```
cor(mtcars)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `corr.test` from `psych` where you can get both the `r` and `p` values.

```
library(psych)
m1 <- corr.test(mtcars)
m1$r
m1$p
```